# Python AST to dictionary structure

Tags: python, json, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the Python `ast` module to parse expressions like `X >= 13 and Y == W`. What I need is to transform this expression in a pre-order dictionary found below:

```
{
  "function": "and",
  "args": [
    {
      "function": ">=",
      "args": [
        {
          "variable": "X"
        },
        {
          "value": 13
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "function": "==",
      "args": [
        {
          "variable": "Y"
        },
        {
          "variable": "W"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Python AST gives me the benefit of validating syntax and differencing variables from values. The following code does a basic parsing but notice the output is not pre-order and I'm not entirely sure how to procede:

```
import ast
class ExclusionParser(ast.NodeVisitor):
    tree = ''

    def append(self, expr):
        self.tree += expr

    def visit_And(self, node):
        self.append("and ")

    def visit_Lt(self, node):
        self.append("< ")

    def visit_Gt(self, node):
        self.append("> ")

    def visit_Eq(self, node):
        self.append("== ")

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        self.append("value: %s " % node.n)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        self.append("variable: %s " % node.id)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        """Called if no explicit visitor function exists for a node."""
        self.append("(")
        for field, value in ast.iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                        self.visit(item)
            elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                self.visit(value)
        self.append(")")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = ExclusionParser()
    p = ast.parse("X > 13 and Y == W")
    v.visit(p)
    print(v.tree)
```

**output**

```
(((and (variable: X > value: 13 )(variable: Y == variable: W ))))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected result?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: the expected result is the dictionary on top of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these small changes - I've added `'`s and commas:

```
import ast
class ExclusionParser(ast.NodeVisitor):
    tree = ''

    def append(self, expr):
        self.tree += expr

    def visit_And(self, node):
        self.append("'func:and', ")

    def visit_Lt(self, node):
        self.append("'func:lt', ")

    def visit_Gt(self, node):
        self.append("'func:gt', ")

    def visit_Eq(self, node):
        self.append("'func:eq', ")

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        self.append("'value:%s', " % node.n)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        self.append("'variable:%s', " % node.id)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        """Called if no explicit visitor function exists for a node."""
        self.append("[")
        for field, value in ast.iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, ast.AST):
                        self.visit(item)
            elif isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                self.visit(value)
        self.append("], ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = ExclusionParser()
    p = ast.parse("X > 13 and Y == W")
    v.visit(p)
    tree = ast.literal_eval(v.tree[:-2])
    print(tree)
```

At this point `tree` is a valid list:

```
[[['func:and', ['variable:X', 'func:gt', 'value:13'], ['variable:Y', 'func:eq', 'variable:W']]]]
```

If you've written `generic_visit` you shouldn't face any difficulties in writing another recursive function that will convert this list of lists into a dictionary. The solution is a bit hacky. (And by "a bit" I mean it's really hacky.) The proper solution would be to modify `generic_visit`, I suppose.

And on a separate note: dictionaries don't preserve the order of theirs elements. Use `OrderedDict` to ensure `function` key goes first.